# How can I fix in Pascal: Incompatible types ("complex type" to "simple type")

Tags: types, pascal

I'm working on a project at school and I have to do some calculations using Pascal and show it on an LC Display. 
My calculations are the following:

```
adc_rd := ADC_read(2);
   textlong := adc_rd*5;
   adc_rd := textlong/1023;
   decim_i := 0.4*adc_rd;
   decim_ii := pow(2.71828,decim_i);
   decim_i := 8.9116*decim_ii;
   FloatToStr_FixLen(decim_i, text4, 6);
   Lcd_Chr(2,6,text4);
```

`decim_i` and `decim_ii` are reals.
I get the following error on the last line `Lcd_Chr(2,6,text4);`:

Incompatible types ("complex type" to "simple type")

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: `Text4` is a string, but `Lcd_Chr` expects a single character. Loop through all characters in the string instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`Text4` is a string, but `Lcd_Chr()` expects a single character.

To solve the problem, loop through all characters in the string:

```
for i := 1 to Length(text4) do Lcd_Chr(1+i,6,text4[i]);
```